# How to automatically give a unique id to each message in flask-socketio?

Tags: javascript

```js
let user_input = $( 'textarea.message' ).val()
let v = user_input.trim()
if (v) {
    let user_name = "You"
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getDate()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear()
    let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes()


    socket.emit( 'my event', {
        msg_id : id, // I want an id assigned every time a message is written here
        user_name : user_name,
        message : user_input ,
        time_now : String(date+","+time)
            } )
    $( 'textarea.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
```

**Does Flask-socketio provide an easy way to do this or should i do it with Javascript myself? **
**What is the best way to do this with Javascript?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let user_input = $( 'textarea.message' ).val()
let v = user_input.trim()
if (v) {
    let user_name = "You"
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getDate()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear()
    let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes()

    if (typeof id == 'undefined') {
        id = 0
    }

    function plus() {
        id += 1;
        return id
    }

    socket.emit( 'my event', {
        msg_id : plus(), // Each new message id will increase by 1 digit
        user_name : user_name,
        message : user_input ,
        time_now : String(date+","+time)
            } )
    $( 'textarea.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
```

I did this the simple my way.I will restore the chat history every time the user logs on to the site and and I'll take the last id in the chat history and continue with it.So, I have defined a unique and simple id for each message.

Answer (score 0):

I assume You can use built in python uuid library for generating unique id

```
import uuid
unique_id = uuid.uuid4()
print(unique_id)  // UUID('8441edfd-297c-4bb7-8803-aee9f5675e36')
```

Comment: I want to handle this on the javascript side,because I will add the messages with the same id name to html. '$( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<p class='user_msg' id=msg.id>' +msg.message+ '</p>' )' something like that. ps(Bende turkum kardes istersen turkce yanitlaya bilirsin)

Comment: Doesn't socketio really offer a simple method for this? A simple id increasing only 1 digit in each message. id=1, id=2, id=3